# I don't understand the relation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the relation
$$e^{ix} - 1 =e^{ix/2}\cdot 2i \cdot \sin(x/2).$$
I don't understand why that is true, but I do know the relation 
$$\sin (x) = \frac {e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
However I don't see where the 1 came from.

Comment: Plug in $x/2$ for $x$, clear fractions, and multiply by $e^{ix/2}$.  The $e^{-ix/2}$ cancels the $e^{ix/2}$ to give 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
e^{ix}-1&=e^{ix/2}(e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2})\\
&=e^{ix/2}\,(2i)\,\left(\frac{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}}{2i}\right)\\
&=e^{ix/2}\,2i\,\sin(x/2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand,

Comment: Just factor out  $e^{ix/2}$.

Comment: Ya sorry after the edit it became clear, thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome.  My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x = {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\over 2i}={e^{2ix}-1\over 2ie^{ix}}$$

So, $e^{2ix}-1=2ie^{ix}\sin x$, now substituting $x/2$ for $x$ gives
$$e^{ix}-1=2ie^{ix/2}sin(x/2).$$